# Getting File Read Error using python Speech Recognition after converting mp4 to wav

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, mp4

I have been using the following script to batch convert mp4 files to wav, and the second script to write speech to text.
I had run that successfully for a while, and converted some 2000 audio files. All files are less than 60 seconds in length.
Then suddenly speech_recognition stopped working and would give the following error for each file.

"*File Read Error: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format*"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code for converting mp4 to wav:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#convert mp4 to wav
import os
import sys
import glob
from pydub import AudioSegment


folder_path = input("Enter the path for the folder/directory : ")
print("\n Processing...")

#Remove quotes from string
if folder_path[0]=="\"":
    folder_path = folder_path[1:]
if folder_path[-1] == "\"":
    folder_path = folder_path[:-1]

os.chdir(folder_path)
folder = os.listdir(folder_path)

#Count files
wavList = glob.glob(folder_path + r"\*.wav")
mp4List = glob.glob(folder_path + r"\*.mp4")

if(input(str(len(mp4List)) + r" '.mp4' files & " + str(len(wavList)) + r" '.wav' files found. Continue (y/n) : ") != "y"):
    print('canceled by user')
    exit()

#loop through files
print(folder_path)
#for srcfile in folder:     #loop in folder only
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    os.chdir(subdir)
    for srcfile in files:
        print(srcfile)
        if(srcfile[-4:]==".mp4"):     
            wavfile = srcfile[:-3] + "wav"
            print(wavfile)
            if (os.path.isfile(wavfile)):
                if sys.argv[0] == "a":
                    os.remove(wavfile)
            if not (os.path.isfile(wavfile)):
                infile = os.path.join(folder_path, srcfile)
                print(infile)
                wavpath = os.path.join(folder_path, wavfile)
                print(wavpath)
                audio = AudioSegment.from_file(infile, format = "mp4")
                audio.export(wavpath, format = "WAV")
```

And this is my function for audio to text.
I truncated it, as I had a lot of options for speech recognition engines, but it's not getting that far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import json
import atexit

text_count = 0
fail_count = 0
skip_count = 0

def get_audio_text(audio_file, TRANSLATE_OPTION):
    txt = audio_file

    # use the audio file as the audio source
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    try:
        with sr.AudioFile(audio_file) as source:
            audio = r.record(source)  # ERROR HERE
    except Exception as e:
        errStr = "File Read Error: " + str(e)
        print(errStr)
        return errStr

    if(TRANSLATE_OPTION == "s" or TRANSLATE_OPTION == "sphinx"):
        # recognize speech using Sphinx
        try:
            txt = r.recognize_sphinx(audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            txt ="Sphinx could not understand audio"
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            txt ="Sphinx error; {0}".format(e)

    elif(TRANSLATE_OPTION == "g" or TRANSLATE_OPTION == "google"):
        # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
        try:
            # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
            # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
            txt = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            txt = "Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio"
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            txt = "Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e)
    
    return txt
```

running on Windows 10. Tried with python3.10 and python3.9

Comment: Would it be possible it comes from corrupted files (incomplete download, for instance)? To answer your question, we will need a focus on the problem from your side. Could you identify a [minimal, reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For instance, is it related to given files, or does it always occur after 2000 read files?

Comment: Hi Leonard,
To clarify:
I would batch run particular folders, first converting mp4s, then transcribing voice to text. Initially I tried using some conversion software for converting the mp4s. I managed only a few hundred this way before finding it too tedious and writing the python function. 
I then continued converting and transcribing several more folders, resulting in ~2000 files processed, and another few thousand in my backlog. 
Then suddenly the process stopped working and all remaining wav files get the error. Even files previous processed successfully now error out.

Comment: Hi Leonard. I was making up the minimum reproducing example when I found my error. 

At some point I accidentally must have changed an if statement from looking for ".wav" to looking for ".mp4". 
In short, I'm an idiot. 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It wasn't in this function at all. I somehow started feeding mp4's to the function instead of .wav's.

this was a classic case of me assuming that the calling code did not have a problem, and then finding that it DID. (yes, I should have shared it all).

Correct calling code:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    os.chdir(subdir)
    for file in files:
        #print(file, file[-4:])     #for debugging
        if(file[-4:]==".wav"):

            txt = get_audio_text(full_path, trans_optn)
```

INCORRECT calling code

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    os.chdir(subdir)
    for file in files:
        #print(file, file[-4:])     #for debugging
        if(file[-4:]==".mp4"):
            txt = get_audio_text(full_path, trans_optn)
```

tbh I really don't know how I managed to screw that up.